# Load rows/checkbox state selection from URL

Tags: javascript, python, jquery

I'm in this situation

[image]

I try to load my datatables with checkbox selected

I have 2 kind of urls: rows unselected and rows/checkbox selected

```
http://localhost:5000/?page=1&length=10
http://localhost:5000/?page=1&length=25&badge=ebooks
```

and

```
http://localhost:5000/?page=1&length=25&badge=ebooks&id=Il+Piccolo+%2314+settembre+2023
```

for example a checkbox is selected when you can see `&id=` inside url

But when I load table with `&id=...` table doesn't return checkbox/rows state selection, it change url into something this

```
http://localhost:5000/?page=1&length=10&badge=ebooks
```

**PROBLEM**: The main problem seems to be related to how the URL is manipulated and how selected rows are handled when performing a search or changing URL parameters.
I am using the state of the DataTable to save the IDs of the selected rows. However, when the page is reloaded with a URL that contains the row IDs, the selected rows are not correctly restored
OK, my relevant code is this

```
    initComplete: function() {
        var api = this.api();

        // Search bar management
        api.columns().every(function() {
            var that = this;
            $('input', this.footer()).on('input', function() {
                if (that.search() !== this.value) {
                    that.search(this.value).draw();
                    if (this.value != '') {
                        history.pushState(null, '', '/?search=' + encodeURIComponent(this.value));
                    } else {
                        history.pushState(null, '', '/');
                    }
                }
            });
        });

        // Highlight the selected rows
        api.rows('.selected-row').nodes().to$().addClass('selected-row');

        // Select rows based on URL parameters
        var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        var selectedRows = urlParams.getAll('id');
        selectedRows.forEach(rowId => {
            // Find the checkbox corresponding to the ID and simulate a click on it
            var checkbox = $('input[name="id[]"][data-id="' + rowId + '"]');
            checkbox.prop('checked', true).trigger('change');
            checkbox.closest('tr').addClass('selected-row');
        });

        // If there are search parameters, apply them to the table
        var searchParam = urlParams.get('search');
        if (searchParam) {
            api.search(searchParam).draw();
        }

        // Block to keep ID in URL
        var currentUrl = new URL(window.location.href);
        var idParam = urlParams.get('id');
        if (idParam) {
            currentUrl.searchParams.set('id', idParam);
        }
        history.replaceState(null, '', currentUrl);
    }
```

and this

```
    columnDefs: [
        {
            targets: 0,
            visible: true,
            searchable: false,
            orderable: false,
            render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                // Add the data-id attribute to the checkbox with the row ID value
                return '<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" data-id="' + row.id + '" value="' + $('<div/>').text(data).html() + '">';
            }
        }
    ],
```

The solution I thought of was to simulate clicks, but maybe is not the best way

[HERE](https://pastebin.com/pyaiBvu0) is the complete javascript code that I use and here is python relevant part

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.String(80), primary_key=True)
    badge = db.Column(db.String(80))
    extra = db.Column(db.String(80))
    username = db.Column(db.String(80))  # Added 'username' column

    def to_dict(self, selected_rows):
        return {
            'id': self.id,
            'badge': self.badge,
            'extra': self.extra,
            'username': self.username,
            'selected': str(self.id) in selected_rows
        }
```

and search function

```
@app.route('/search', methods=['POST'])
def search():
    badge = request.form.get('badge') or request.args.get('badge')
    start = int(request.form.get('start', 0))
    length = int(request.form.get('length', 10))
    searchTerm = request.form.get('search[value]')
    
    # Access selectedRows from the prompt
    selected_rows = request.form.getlist('selectedRows[]')

    query = User.query

    if badge:
        query = query.filter(User.badge == badge)

    if searchTerm:
        query = query.filter((User.id.ilike(f"%{searchTerm}%")) | 
                             (User.badge.ilike(f"%{searchTerm}%")) | 
                             (User.extra.ilike(f"%{searchTerm}%")) |
                             (User.username.ilike(f"%{searchTerm}%")))

    data = query.offset(start).limit(length).all()

    # Pass selectedRows to the to_dict function
    return jsonify({
        'data': [user.to_dict(selected_rows) for user in data],
        'recordsTotal': User.query.count(),
        'recordsFiltered': query.count(),
    })
```

**Attempt to fix the problem**: to avoid simulating the click I tried to modify the code also in this way so that the setting of the row and checkbox status occurs directly without having to simulate the change event. But nothing

```
   selectedRows.forEach(rowId => {
        // Find the checkbox corresponding to the ID
        var checkbox = $('input[name="id[]"][data-id="' + rowId + '"]');
        
        // Set the 'checked' property of the checkbox directly
        checkbox.prop('checked', true);
    
        // Add the 'selected-row' class to the closest row
        checkbox.closest('tr').addClass('selected-row');
    });
    
    // Trigger the 'change' event for the checkboxes
    $('input[name="id[]"]').trigger('change');
```